# Android SDK installation error - "no buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed

Tags: sockets, android, installation, buffer-overflow, connection

I am trying to get my environment setup to develop an android app so I downloaded the SDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html).
After unpacking the files and running the SDK Setup.exe, the Android SDK and AVD manager opens up.
During the installation process, I got an error stating the following:

> Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason: HTTPS SSL error. You might want to force download through HTTP in the settings.

So then I proceed to the SETTINGS tab and activated the check box which states:

> Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://

Then click save and apply.  A box flashes on screen, which appears to be the previous box which showed the error, except this time, the progress bar races from 0 to 100% in about a second and then disappears.  So clicking the FORCE option seemed to have worked for that issue.

Now, I click on the AVAILABLE PACKAGES tab which is where the Android manager actually downloads all the available resources including every "SDK Platform Android Vx.x" and every "Google API by Google Inc., API x, revision x"

There are green check marks in every check box indicating that I need to download every update.
SO I click INSTALL SELECTED.

The confirmation page comes up.  Again, I click INSTALL ACCEPTED.

The INSTALLATION ARCHIVES box pops up and this is where I get stuck.  I receive the following errors and I'm not sure what to do from here..

> Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 7, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Skipping 'Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 7, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK  Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 1' which was not installed.
>   Downloading Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 7, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Skipping 'Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 6, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK  Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1' which was not installed.
>   Downloading Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 6, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Skipping 'Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 5, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1' which was not installed.
>   Downloading Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 5, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 2
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Skipping 'Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 4, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK  Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 2' which was not installed.
>   Downloading Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 4, revision 2
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 3
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Skipping 'Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 3, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK  Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 3' which was not installed.
>   Downloading Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 3, revision 3
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.1, API 2, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Downloading Usb Driver package, revision 3
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed

I did some googling on "No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?)" and apparently it is a socket issue that typically occurs when a database query is called and there are a large number of TCP connections.

But beyond that I'm completely stuck.  Can't find anything on my issue relating to Android SDK installation and I don't really know where to turn to continue with the SDK installation.

Thank you in advance!

---

Anyone familiar with installing the Android sdk, is there an alternative way of downloading the SDK components OTHER then using the Android SDK management utility??

Obviously something about my system isn't playing nicely with this manager but I'm completely stuck here and really want to get going..

Thanks again..

[Screenshots]
Available packages for download:
http://i45.tinypic.com/9igs48.jpg

--

Installation errors:
http://i50.tinypic.com/260fxox.jpg

Comment: It looks like a problem with the download server. Just try again.

Comment: NO dice.
I went through the same process on my other pc and didn't run into the issue.

However, I've tried several times, here on this PC and I continually get the "max connections" errors.

Comment: you need to know for sure bittorrent or any other "sharing"xD program is running like utorrent bitcomment limewire cause the connecdt this fixed it for me